# Laravel Modelname:find($id) or ModelName::findorFail($id)?

Tags: database, laravel, model

Hi I just start to use Laravel and was walking through some tutorial and get stucked at something:
here is my controller and model:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Message;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MessageController extends Controller
{
  public function create(Request $request)
  {
    $message=new Message();
    $message->col1=$request->col1;
    $message->col2=$request->col2;
    $message->save();
    return redirect('/home');
  }
  public function vewrec($id)
  {
    $message=Message::findOrFail($id);
    return view('record',['message'=>$message]);
  }
}
```

and model code:

```
  namespace App;

  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

  class Message extends Model
  {
    protected$fillable=['col1','col2'];
  }
```

Should I add something(methods) in the model(Message) to find the id?
if possible, may I ask for this method that pull the data from database and check the ID? return null or  return one record as an element of an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine But in your model there isnt space between `protected` and variable `$fillable` so please correct it

```
protected $fillable=['col1','col2'];
```

To get results in array just add `toArray()` in your eloquent

```
$message=Message::findOrFail($id)->toArray();
```

`findorfail()` will throw an error if the record is not found so if you want to return null instead of an error use `find()`

```
$message=Message::find($id)->toArray();
```

Comment: thanks, I know what is happening, it is because I am using phpstorm which doesn't fully support laravel. Visual studio code works perfect, anyway thank you for your time and I did correct that error you pointed to me,

Answer (score 0):

findOrFail function will return a collection. If you need array then you can use `toArray()` function.

```
public function vewrec($id)
{
    $message=Message::findOrFail($id);
    if(count($message)!=0){
        $message = $message->toArray();
    }else{
        $message = NULL;
    }
    return view('record',compact('message'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is good, but in model:

```
protected$fillable=['col1','col2'];
```

Just repair it to be:

```
protected $fillable=['col1', 'col2'];
```

As for public function vewrec($id), it can return error or return an element. Perhaps if you don't want the error to be appeared, use Model::find($id).
Hope it helps.